# Watch changes in a .jspx page with session hash

Tags: javascript, forms, watch, jspx

I want to watch changes in a webpage but I don't know how to get a URL to add it to a watcher.

This is how you reach the desired page. First you go to this [page](https://sede.cordoba.es:4443/seleccion/web-empleo/faces/empleo.jspx). (If you get a *Service Temporarily Unavailable* error try forcing a reload, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click Reload or open it in a new page with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Intro</kbd>)

There are several items beginning with "Convocatoria". Every item has several sections: *OPE*, *Tipo de personal*, etc. and then 4 links. The page which you are redirected to when you click the 3rd (*Tablón de anuncios*) is the one I'm interested in. Choose one (the first, for example) and click *Tablón de anuncios*.The highlighted part is to be watched, i.e. if there is any line added to the table (only one ATOW).

[image: Text to watch highlighted]

Inspecting the element (that 3rd link) shows

```
<a onclick="submitForm('_id2',1,{source:'_id63'});return false;" class="x8w" href="#">Tablón de anuncios</a>
```

Function `submitForm` is in `https://sede.cordoba.es:4443/seleccion/web-empleo/adf/jsLibs/Common10_1_3_4_0.js` (line 2749). If I set a break at the beginning of that function, step by step, I reach line 3013

```
form.submit();
```

And this is all I know to do. The page loads but the loaded resources then are pictures, css, js, etc. The only page I see in *Network* has the same URL as the first (`...faces/empleo.jspx`).

- A valid answer would be "This is the URL you need", if you can easily infer how `submitForm('_id2',1,{source:'_id63'})` transform into that URL. Or if you explain the path of actions to find it out.
- Or a documented source and an explanation of why this is impossible (without hacking the server or so).

---

**Solution in Android (or so it seems)**

Looking for info on this topic I stumbled upon this [free Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.webalert) (there's also a pro version, but you don't need it for this) so I tried it. It has an embedded browser: you can open a page, navigate wherever you want to, select an element (or group of them) inside that final page and watch it/them.

I navigated to the page I needed, selected the table and the program showed me only the text inside it to compare for changes, so I think when there's a new row it will alert me.

You can configure every alert *to use javascript or not*, so I selected to use it. For now, it showed no alert so it seems that reaches the desired page and not the first I opened, *but you cannot be sure until there's a change* (and don't know when it will but I'll inform here of the outcome).

I would have preferred a watch from Windows (and I'll keep searching) but for now I feel confident enough. When watching pages I prefer to use two different solutions just in case and here all the more.

***Almost* solution**

The `curl` command provided by **Marks Polakovs** gave me an idea. If you can download the intended page (with `curl` or whatever) to a `file.htm` inside a `folder`, it's easy to start a `localhost` web server (I know PHP and python do it but there must be a bunch of them) to share that `path` and watch `localhost/file.htm` for changes.

All you have to do then is to run a Windows task every *x* minutes/hours to refresh `file.htm`. I *suppose* a headless browser (PhantomJS or the like) would do the job of downloading, virtually clicking the link and saving the page, but I *actually don't know* how to do it.

No answer provides a working proof of concept of its idea but at least **Marks Polakovs** tried it and gave valuable hints, so I'll upvote it and the system will assign him the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping through the code for the `onclick` handler you see that at some point it finds the form with ID `_id2` (line 2775) and, after adding some parameters through hidden fields (`{source:'_id63'}`), submits it. (To find this out, open `Common10_1_3_4_0.js` in the Chrome DevTools, place a breakpoint on line 2758, and step through the execution.) The request itself is a POST to `https://sede.cordoba.es:4443/seleccion/web-empleo/faces/empleo.jspx` with the following POST parameters:

```
oracle.adf.faces.FORM: _id2
oracle.adf.faces.STATE_TOKEN: 5
event: 
source: _id63
```

Some of them were there already in the form's HTML, while others were added by `submitForm()`.

So, to answer your question, your HTTP watcher will need to support POST, and if it does, add that URL with those parameters to it.

EDIT: here's a cURL command (escaped for Windows cmd):

```
curl -X POST "https://sede.cordoba.es:4443/seleccion/web-empleo/faces/empleo.jspx" --data "oracle.adf.faces.FORM=_id2^&oracle.adf.faces.STATE_TOKEN=9^&event=^&source=_id63"
```

Comment: I tried your `curl` command adding `-o result.htm` but the page downloaded was the same as always, not the intended. BTW, you must either escape ampersands or double-quote the parameter: if you do both, the carets appear in the final command.

Comment: No change with `-X POST`, but thanks for the hint. I managed to download the right page from another machine with [this command](https://pastebin.com/wwjvTehr) but the second machine gets Internet with ICS from the first and maybe IP has something to do with the session hash. Would you try this command from your machine?

Comment: The `curl`commands work during some hours but eventually expires.

Answer (score 0):

The form containing the url that the data is posted to is in the document. In your specific example the form looks like this:

```
<form id="_id2" ... method="POST" action="/seleccion/web-empleo/faces/empleo.jspx;jsessionid=efba550217d9f5adbe8cbe05c049fbc967ac5e5fe755adb2a53bf3a41aa5eaa8.e3iMchmQbhuNe3aLbN8Rax8Nay0">
```

So, if you want to intercept calls to this url you can do the following:

```
var _oldSubmitForm = submitForm
submitForm = function (form, doValidate, parameters) {
  console.log(document.forms[form].action)
  _oldSubmitForm(form, doValidate, parameters)
}
```

I would not recommend doing it like this, but I don't know the situation you are in and how much control you have over the generated HTML.

---

**Update**

As cdlvcdlv explained, the above is not enough. The situation here is quite tricky. The desired content is only rendered when the form is posted with specific information. Just posting the form will not work as the server expects a Java session to be available.

The only way to get the server to display the desired page is by performing the following steps:

- Do a `GET` request to https://sede.cordoba.es:4443/seleccion/web-empleo/faces/empleo.jspx and extract the cookie (the `Set-Cookie` header) from the response.
- Do a `POST` request with the appropriate information and supply the cookie with the request (the `Cookie` header). As an alternative the `jesessionid` can be supplied to the url.

If you want to have a service that can be given a url and just loads the page you need to set up a server yourself to perform the steps above. This server would perform the 2 actions and return the appropriate content.

To summarize: there is no way to get the correct page rendered using a single `GET` request.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I want to watch changes in that page so you should tell how much control I have, i.e. _none_. Of course _you_ can access with that URL from _your_ browser. As you can see, it has got encoded a unique session hash (`;jsessionid=`), only valid for you in the browser you used when clicked that 3rd link. ...

Comment: ... If you try to open [your suggested link](https://sede.cordoba.es:4443/seleccion/web-empleo/faces/empleo.jspx;jsessionid=efba550217d9f5adbe8cbe05c049fbc967ac5e5fe755adb2a53bf3a41aa5eaa8.e3iMchmQbhuNe3aLbN8Rax8Nay0) from another browser or machine, you will end in the initial page. That link is created dynamically for you and your browser and it doesn't work (of course I tried) for anyone else.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to "watch" the url changing. Clicking on that link submits the form back to the same source url, triggering a complete page reload.

Comment: How do you know? Without documented source, it might as well be you don't know how to do it. Maybe there's a watcher that covers this?

Comment: Because a) I generally understand how browsers, js, and the internet works and b) you haven't provided nearly enough information to possibly come up with a solution. As I said, there is no "watcher". Javascript runs in the context of the page it is loaded in. When you reload the page, the js reloads.

Comment: It seems there's is a free app in Android that does it. I also suggest there should be a way to do it in Windows.